# Perl module expect.pm is not available for windows 64 bit system

Tags: perl, activeperl

I am using Activeperl for my windows 64 bit machine, I want to use `expect.pm` module for windows 64 bit, but getting these errors:

```
Can't locate Expect.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Expect module) (@INC contains: D:/Software/eclips/.metadata/.plugins/org.epic.debug
```

I have googled it many are saying this module is not supported in windows 64 bit. Can somebody guide me how can I install it, if not so do I need to shift Linux environment?

Answer (score 2):

According to [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod#Can_I_use_this_module_with_ActivePerl_on_Windows?) the only way for this to work in Windows is through [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).

This appears to be due to a dependency on [IO:tty](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/IO-Tty-1.12/Tty.pm), which has the same suggestion to use it through Cygwin.

Comment: Well, any virtual unix machine will do, not just cygwin.

Comment: @ikegami: cygwin is not a virtual machine, it is a linux emulation layer and environment in Windows

Comment: @ysth, And that's the definition of a virtual machine. "In computing, a virtual machine (VM) is an emulation of a particular computer system. "

Comment: it does not therefore follow that an emulation of a particular computer system is a virtual machine.  cygwin is not a virtual machine.

Answer (score 2):

It won't run on Windows. Expect creates a pseudo-tty to try fool the child program into not buffering its output. Windows doesn't have ttys.

Comment: would have been better as a comment or edit to Degustaf's answer

Comment: @ysth, Explaining that it can't possibly run on Windows is not a comment when the question asks if he needs to switch to Linux to use the module. As for duplicating Degustaf's answer, I didn't see any other answers when I posted. Besides, i don't care for his answer that "you need to use another OS if you want it to work in Windows".

Comment: well, then, maybe it should be a comment on the question.  because it isn't an answer to (paraphrasing only lightly) "how do I use Expect.pm with ActivePerl, or do I need to switch to Linux", which Degustaf's answer does nicely answer.

Comment: @ysth, Why do you think I need to spell out that you can't use a module on Windows after explaining that the the module relies on features Windows doesn't have? but fine, I did it.